# Create multiple dataframes with for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, file

I need to compile grades from 10 files named quiz2, quiz3 [...], quiz11.

I have the following transformation:

- Import the xls to df with pandas
- Get only the 4 renamed columns
- Keep only the highest grade if there is multiple values for the same ID

The code for one dataframe is the following:

```
quiz2=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\llarbodiere\Desktop\Perso\grade compil\quiz\quiz2.xls')
quiz2=quiz2.rename({'Nom d’utilisateur': 'ID', 'Note totale': 'quiz2'}, axis='columns')
quiz2=quiz2[['Nom','Prénom','ID','quiz2']]
quiz2.groupby("ID").max().sort_values("Nom").fillna(0)
```

I want to iterate the same transformations for all the quizzes from quiz2 to quiz11. I have tried a for loop but it did not worked.

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Show the for loop that you tried, and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You could generate the file name dynamically by looping through a range of numbers from 1 to 11 and concatenating the number to the file name and suffix.

```
#create an empty dataframe for collecting loop results
cumulative_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a'])

#loop through a range of numbers from 1 to 11
for x in range(1,11):

    #generate the file name
    file = 'quiz'+str(x)+'.xls'

    df=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/llarbodiere/Desktop/Perso/grade compil/quiz/'+file)
    df=df.rename({'Nom d’utilisateur': 'ID', 'Note totale': 'quiz'}, axis='columns')
    df=df[['Nom','Prénom','ID','quiz']]
    df.groupby("ID").max().sort_values("Nom").fillna(0)
    
    #add the df active in the loop to the cumulative df
    pd.concat([cumulative_df, df])

print(cumulative_df)
```

EDIT: the example above is for the specific file names you mentioned. This could be generalized further to work for all files in a given directory, for example.